# Multiple images sent to client in one session

Tags: image, http, client-server

When you load an image in a browser, a so called handshake takes place between the client and the server where this picture is being sent.
This handshake then happens for every picture the client downloads. So if you have many images, downloading them can become slow, largely because the client and the server are alway remaking this handshake procedure. This slows connection speeds, especially if you are for instance on the Ipad. There are some methods to get by this, such as by sending only a single large image, and then use clips within that image, as if they are a single image. But that clutters the code etc. It complicates things.

Is there any way to send multiple images via a single handshake to the client thereby avoiding this clipping procedure as well as client-server communication overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base64 encode it and send it via javascript. Expect about 4/3 size increase.

An example is shown here:

http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html

Comment: thanks, and more stuff here: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to

Comment: Personally, I think you're barking up the right tree for mobile. This is why: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il4swGfTOSM&feature=youtu.be